# Process cannot access the file exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.io.file

As it was common to guess what kind of reason for this exception. But let me explain the exact scenario which am facing . Please find the overview of my code block.

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> Method1());

 private void Method1()
 {

     //A process which loads the file and uploads it to server. If the file was large, it will take some amount of time.
     using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
           //Upload file
        }

    //Once uploads deletes from local.
    File.Delete(path);
 }
```

Before uploading the file delete method was called as I have used separate tasks . So I get the exception that process cannot access the file.

I should delete the file once upload was over. Need some suggestions on that.

Comment: can you provide more code because from first look it seems ok ...here filePath and path is same ??

Comment: Simple. Do it after the Upload completed. How do you upload the file?

Comment: @PranayRana yes both are same

Comment: What happens after  `Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> Method1());` ? Anything related to the file?

Comment: you can check updaed answer which make use of singling construct of .net

Comment: Doesn't seem like there should be a problem with your code. There is no multithreading wrt to the file. So either you are lying about your error, or you are missing details. Please send us a [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TPL Continuewith

you can also make use of contnuewith over here because

1. you want to updload file
2. once update done you want to delete file

than you can do this

```
Task t =Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> Method1());//remove delete file form method one 
t.ContinueWith((as)=> {File.Delete(path);} );
```

there might be syntax error in above code so please solve it in visual studio

---

Singling Construct

As you are updloading and delete file on different threds that I suggest you 
make use of signaling construct

```
public class test 
{
 private static AutoResetEvent event_2 = new AutoResetEvent(false);

 public void uploadfile()
 {
   ///do file updating 
   //than give signale 
   event_2.set();
 }

 public void deletefile()
 {
    event_2.WaitOne();
    //delete file 
 }
}
```

---

it doesn't seem thread issue , it look like file you want to delete is not present so its better you check file exists or not by file exits method

```
if (File.Exists(path))
{
 File.Delete(path);
}
```

Comment: should be a "file does not exist" exception then, OP said " process cannot access the file."

Comment: @jHilscher - I think better to use signaling here as two threads depend on each other .. as 1 thread upload data and than next thread delete file ... TPL ContinueWith also helpful here